# Problem with $\sup A, \min A, \max A$ and $\inf A$.

Tags: analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Having the set:
 $A=\{\frac1n+(-1)^n:n\in \mathbb N\}$
I found with some process (separate it to $n=2k$ and $n=2k+1, k\in \mathbb N$) that  $\sup A=\frac32,\inf A=-1 \notin A$, so $\min A$ doesn't exist. My problem is at $\max A$, because $n \in \mathbb N$, I thought that there isn't $\max A$, but in my book it's equal to $\frac32$.

Comment: Since $\frac32=\frac12+(-1)^2$, $\frac32\in A$.

Comment: Who ever said $A\subset \mathbf N$?

Comment: The relatively complete version of the notation: $$ A = \{x \in \mathbb R\colon x = 1/n + (-1)^n, n \in \mathbb N^*\}. $$

Comment: Oh, now I finally see. Thank you so much !!